# ESS and company-mode integration

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I have installed ESS and company-mode. Now, when I spawn up a ESS R process, I am able to see the suggestions from the company system. However, if I try to look for the documentation by pressing `F1` on the company's suggestion box, it says 'No documentation available'. Similarly, source also is not available when pressing `C-w`.

When I try to get the ESS's documentation by pressing `C-c C-v`, I am able to see the documentation. Can you help me figure out what is wrong here?

```
 ess-version: 15.09-devel [elpa: 20150708.1130
 Company version: 0.8.7
```

My (relevant) .emacs configuration:

`(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(require 'ess-site)`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you file an issue on GitHub? Might be best way to get an answer